# How to use a checkbox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tcheckbox

Right now, I have the code:

```
begin
If odd(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_snapshot)) then
If CheckBox1.Checked then
begin
```

And then it continues on with the rest of the code. Is that the correct way of doing that, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I want it where, if the user checks the checkbox, it will continue with that procedure, but if the checkbox is NOT checked, it will continue a different procedure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you suggest is a perfectly legal way to determine if a checkbox is checked. The code doing so might look like

```
if checkBox.Checked then begin
    //do whatever needed for checked checkbox
end
```

or like this

```
if checkBox.Checked then begin
    //do whatever needed for checked checkbox
end else begin
    //do whatever needed for unchecked checkbox
end
```

Just remember that the value you obtained from Checked property corresponds to the checkbox's state at the moment when you obtained the value.

Comment: For that second one, how would I implement my check if Print Screen is pressed? Or, if possible, could you put that someone into that second code?

Comment: It's the same. You have an event handler for "KeyPressed" or similar event. Inside you check if it was really the key of interest pressed. If it is, invoke the code that reads checkbox state and acts accordingly.

Comment: Alright, I have this:
begin
if CheckBox1.Checked then begin
If odd(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_snapshot)) Then
begin
//code here
end
else begin
//different code here
end;

Which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if DT.FieldByName('name_of_checkbox').AsBoolean=True then begin ..... end;
// In this case dt is TADOquery that you had used in your program.
```

Answer (score -1):

since you are using 2 if-statements, you might also combine them into one:

```
if odd(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_snapshot)) and CheckBox1.Checked then
begin
  ...
  ...
end;
```

The second part of the if-statement (checkbox1.Checked) will only be evaluated if the first one evaluates to True. (Since Delphi uses [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

Comment: Please edit this - Delphi does **not** necessarily use short-circuit evaluation, the behaviour depends on the `{$B}` compiler directive or the respective command line switch!